# Does HSTS preload includes subdomains?

Tags: hsts

i know that you can preload your domain if you have everything with a valid HTTPS vertificate, but after preloading the domain if i go to subdomain.example.com is it going to me preload the same way as example.com is preloaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HSTS preload and requisites on domain - subdomains must be added too?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/210744/hsts-preload-and-requisites-on-domain-subdomains-must-be-added-too)

Comment: actually in the other comment i asked if it was possible to not include some subdomains in the preload directive. here i ask if all subdomains are preloaded. anyway... the quick answer i got here clarified my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can see at https://hstspreload.org/ that it is a requirement to include subdomains:

> The includeSubDomains directive must be specified.

Comment: yea i saw that but i wasn't sure if the subdomains were preloaded too or it was just a requisite... thanks!!